# enter right postcode format, it shows Invalid when i run the follow code

Tags: java

Here is the code, when i enter `A1B 2C3`, the answer shows invalid. 
I wonder where the mistake is in the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PostCode {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter post code:");
        String postCode=input.nextLine().toUpperCase();

        if(postCode.matches("[A-Z]\\d\\[A-Z]\\d\\[A-Z]\\d")) {
            System.out.print("Valid");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Invalid");    
        }

        input.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your regex says `[letter][digit][letter][digit][letter][digit]` and your input string is `[letter][digit][letter][space][digit][letter][digit]`, ergo change your regex.

Comment: when I type A1B2C3, the output shows INVALID

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should be:

```
"[A-Z]\\\d\\\\[A-Z]\\\s\\\d\\\\[A-Z]\\\d"
```